# How to stop Chrome mucking with the DOM

Tags: google-chrome, browser, html, website, chromium

Basically, It irritates me that Chrome is mucking around with the DOM on all or nearly all web forms. I realize that this is probably a convenience for auto-filling forms, but I'd like to know how to go about disabling it. sometimes it's extremely annoying, especially if I want to look at a pages source for whatever reason.

[image: ExampleImg]

[image: ExampleDOMImg]

If someone can show me how to go about disabling this I might automate the process to make it possible to just conveniently toggle/untoggle this since I feel like that would be a good solution since if my assumption is correct, I want it more often than not. (Although I dislike seeing it when I mouse-over a field in a HTML form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not default behavior; you actually enabled it through `about:flags`.

Internally (in components/autofill/content/renderer/), the [`attach_predictions_to_dom`](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=attach_predictions_to_dom&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc) variable controls this behavior, and it is enabled according to the feature [`kShowAutofillTypePredictions`](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=kShowAutofillTypePredictions&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc).

This corresponds to the about:flags entry "Show Autofill predictions". Enable/disable it at:

```
chrome://flags/#show-autofill-type-predictions
```